# Tastypie and JSON Field serialization issue

Tags: python, django, tastypie

So I read the following posts without finding the answer:

My model is using a JSONField to store arbitrary data.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    """
        Execution of a Test
    """
    results = JSONField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

In a python shell, I can print this field and it is rendering the following:

```
[{"name": "tata", "result": "toto"}]
```

I modify dehydrate method to remove unicode, but I have the following result:

```
**Dehydrate Method:**
def dehydrate_results(self, bundle):
    results = json.dumps(bundle.obj.results)
    return results 

**Tastypie Result**
"results": "[{\"name\": \"Cash In\", \"result\": \"toto\"}]"
```

I can't use this object in my javascript app... Maybe you can explain me how to have a "normal" json output from tastypie:

```
**Wanted Tastypie Result**
"results": [{"name": "Cash In", "result": "toto"}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't need to provide a custom dehydrate field since `bundle.obj.results` is already a deserialized object from the database.

Rather than provide a custom `dehydrate_results` function, simply specify the `results` field type as being either a `tastypie.fields.DictField` or a `tastypie.fields.ListField` depending on the data you're storing.

eg.

```
from tastypie.fields import ListField

class MyResource(ModelResource):
    results = ListField(attribute='results')
```

Comment: Wow, I thank you so much :) ListField is working really fine!

Comment: DictField is working equally well. Saved me at least an hour of work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The string value is simply encoded json, so you need to decode it inside js:

```
JSON.parse("[{\"name\": \"Cash In\", \"result\": \"toto\"}]")
```

This will give you correct list of objects.